# KSOAP2 AndroidHttpTransport.call connection=null

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

When I try to run my `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` my program errors out, then while stepping through it, i can see that the `connection=null` Is it supposed to be like this? ( I assume not) And if it isn't then can somebody tell me what causes it?

```
private static final String NAMESPACE   =   "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL         =   "http://foo/bar/Service1.asmx";
private static final String METHOD_NAME =  "HelloWorld";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

public void getMessage() {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    Log.i(TAG, "Envelope to String: \n" + String.valueOf(envelope));

    Log.i(TAG, "request to String: \n" + String.valueOf(request));

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
        androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");
        blah = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //Assign it to fahren static variable
        message = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        /*Log.i("HT", blah);
        Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage().toString());*/
    }
}

}
```

This is the debugging as the call is being made:

[image]

This is the view after it errors out:

[image]

Does anybody know what the cause of this could possibly be?

Comment: what is the error when you run the program?

Comment: `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG`